# Let $a_n\searrow 0$, $s_n=\sum_{j=n}^\infty (-1)^{j-n}a_j$. If $\sum s_n^2<\infty$, show $\sum a_n^2<\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n\searrow 0$, $s_n=\sum_{j=n}^\infty (-1)^{j-n}a_j$. If $\sum s_n^2<\infty$, show $\sum a_n^2<\infty$

Clearly, $a_n-a_{n+1}\leq s_n\leq a_n$. But how to do then?

Comment: What is $a_n\searrow 0$?

Comment: @RounakSarkar Same as $a_n \to 0^+$.

Comment: @Milten. I have never seen the notation used by the OP.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Okay. It's not that uncommon. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n^{2}=(s_n+s_{n+1})^{2}\leq 2s_n^{2}+2s_{n+1}^{2}$ and $\sum s_{n+1}^{2} <\infty, \sum s_{n}^{2}<\infty$.